# Laravel: injecting a custom class in a Command class

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, ioc-container, laravel-5.5

I've come across an issue where I have a custom class, `app/TicketFetcher`, being injected into the constructor of `App\Console\Commands/TicketFetch` class, but I'm not sure how to inject a specific instance of `TicketFetcher`, where it takes constructor arguments, without errors.

Instantiation of these classes appear to be handled by Laravel's service container because it automatically injects an instance of my custom class when `TicketFetcher`'s constructor has no argument. Problem arises when there are arguments.

Setup:

```
class TicketFetch extends Command
{
    // $ticketFetcher injected automatically
    public function __construct(TicketFetcher $ticketFetcher)
}

class TicketFetcher
{
    public function __construct(integer $var1, string $var2...) {
}
```

As you can see, I require some initialization variables for `TicketFetcher` to be constructed, so I bound `TicketFetcher` in `AppServiceProvider`.

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $var1 ]] in class App\TicketFetcher

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // Also tried $this->app->instance() and
        // $this->app->when('\App\TicketFetcher')->needs(...)->give(...)
        $this->app->bind(
            '\App\TicketFetcher', 
            new \App\TicketFetcher('some value')
        );
    }
}
```

I'm getting `some value` to pass into `TicketFetcher`'s constructor but still getting an error.

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $var1 ]] in class App\TicketFetcher
```

How do I bind this properly, so that `TicketFetcher` is created correctly?

Comment: Just realized `$this->app->when('App\TicketFetcher')` is actually the right way to do it. Notice no leading slash in `when()`.. doh! how do I bind multiple primitives? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding

Comment: `TicketFetcher::class` works also, provided the class is imported via `use` first

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one of the methods I tried was correct/worked.

```
$this->app->when('App\TicketFetcher')->needs('$var1')->give('some value');
$this->app->when('App\TicketFetcher')->needs('$var2')->give([1, 2]);
```

Note the lack of leading slash. This is what's called [binding a primitive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding), like a string, array, etc. You repeat it for each arguments.

I am still wondering if there is another way to do this, as this seems like it will get very lengthy for a larger project.